# Same column width under colspan

Tags: html, css, html-table

How can I make columns under `colspan` of same width?

I have table header like in example.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>td {border: solid 1px black;}</style>
</head>
<body>
<table style="width: 100%;border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Some header columns or even several(big or small)</td>
        <td colspan="4">pre-defined number of undercolumns</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td><td>11</td><td>111</td><td>1111</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data_row</td><td>4444</td><td>333</td><td>22</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I have created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6brwy20t/4/) that demonstrates this.

Potentially the number of columns (to make same width) could be different. Changing the `table-layout` to `fixed` is not a solution in my case because of existence of other columns.  I can not make them with fixed width since not sure of data content length. I also can not do them with percent width since it is percent of all table, but not column group.

Comment: I still don't have proper solution but use next workaround: i just set `min-width` to column headers as biggest of them(in my case it is possible).

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
td {
    border: solid 1px black;
    width: calc(100%/5);
}
```

And you can divide the width as many columns as you have.

Comment: it not fit me neither. https://jsfiddle.net/6brwy20t/8/  As I said i try to not predefine width of left and right part

Comment: Man you asked to make columns under colspan same width. Try to make your question more clear.

Comment: I'm searching something like `width: calc(100%/5);` where `100%` will be applicable to some column group, but not to whole <table>. Html would be generated as a report dynamycally from XML via XSLT. And it should look cute with 2 columns or 15 in right part

Comment: If you use the <pre>width: calc(80%/5);</pre> the right part will not be affected by the width. But i cant tell it for the left. Im afraid the thing you are looking for can not be done in css dynamically.